# Navigation moves while resizing window

Tags: css, html, navigation

Is there a quick and easy way to keep a navigation not moving while resizing the window ?

What I have at the moment is something like this which is obviously wrong because proportions will change.

I am not sure if I should use a fixed width though ?

```
#mainnav {
position: absolute;
left: 30%;
top: 75px;
width: 50%;
}
```

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: `Is there a quick and easy way to keep a navigation not moving while resizing the window?` Yes, do NOT remove the navigation from *document normal flow*. BTW using `float` and `absolute` together is meaningless   here.

Comment: Sorry I was not using it anyway, copied it from the inspector.

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle or sample to demonstrate the issue in action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on what kind of page you are creating. If you are creating something responsive/interactive, you may need fixed or absolute navigation, but it's hard to tell from the code that you provided.

A more traditional approach would be to wrap your page content in a container with a fixed width:

```
<div id="container">
   <div id="mainnav">...</nav>
   <div id="main-content">...</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#container
{
   width: 1000px;
   margin: 0 auto; // will center your container inside page body, even on resize
}

#mainnav
{
   display : block;
}
```

This way your nav will stay together with the content and wont resize. it's also much easier to manage what's inside the navigation element.